# "Subquery returned more than 1 value", while trying to display data from different tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to display the contents from one or more tables but when there is some repeated date i am getting 'null' as the output

```
 -- table scheme --

CREATE TABLE Employee (Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(130620,1),Name varchar(50) NOT NULL)
create Table Client(Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(101,1),Name varchar(50) NOT NULL)
create Table Project(Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(201,1),ClientId intFOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Client(Id),Name varchar(50) not null)
create table Timelog(Id int primary key identity(1101,1),EmployeeId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(Id),InTime datetime,OutTime datetime,EmployeeProjectId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EmployeeProject(Id)) 
create table EmployeeProject(Id int primary key identity(1,1),EmployeeId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(Id),ProjectId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Project(Id))
create table [User]([Id] [int] primary key identity(2101,1),[EmployeeId] int foreign key references Employee(Id),[UserName] [varchar](50),[PassWord] [varchar](50))




 --stored procedure--
alter proc EmployeeReport(@empid int)
as
begin
declare @inTime time(0)
declare @outTime time(0)
declare @fromDate date
declare @toDate date
declare @clientName varchar(50)
declare @projectName varchar(50)
set @inTime = (select CAST(InTime as time(0)) from Timelog where EmployeeId=@empid)
set @outTime = (select CAST(OutTime as time(0)) from Timelog where EmployeeId = @empid)
set @projectName = (select p.Name from Project p inner join EmployeeProject ep on (ep.ProjectId = p.Id and ep.EmployeeId = @empid) where p.Id=ep.ProjectId)
set @clientName = (select c.name from client c join Project p on p.Name = @projectName where c.Id = p.ClientId)
set @fromDate = (select cast (InTime as date) from Timelog where EmployeeId= @empid)
set @toDate = (select cast (outTime as date) from Timelog where EmployeeId= @empid)

select @fromDate as FromDate,@toDate as ToDate,c.Name as Client,p.Name as Project ,@inTime as InTime,@outTime as OutTime,t.TotalTime
from Timelog t left join Employee e on e.id = t.EmployeeId left join Project p on p.Id = t.EmployeeProjectId left join Client c on c.Id = p.ClientId
where t.EmployeeId = @empid

 print @inTime
 print @outTime
 print @fromDate
 print @toDate
 print @projectName
 end
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EmployeeReport, Line 12
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>    follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EmployeeReport, Line 13
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EmployeeReport, Line 14
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure EmployeeReport, Line 15
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is what the output i am getting:
[image]
[image]

Comment: So what's your question? The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: @Vj charan, When you are using subquery against `=, !=, <, <= , >, >=` operators, you must make sure that the subquery returns only one value. You will get this error, when subquery returns more than one value. Please post the table structure, sample data for solving your `NULL` value issue.

Comment: @Venu i have uploaded the structure

Comment: @Vj charan, Please provide the table schema, test data and desired results in text format. Please refer to below links on how to ask good question. [stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056) & [spaghettidba](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line of your procedure:

```
set @projectName = (select p.Name 
                    from Project p 
                    inner join EmployeeProject ep 
                        on (ep.ProjectId = p.Id and ep.EmployeeId = @empid) 
                    where p.Id=ep.ProjectId)
```

If you run that query on it's own, you will see that it returns more than a single row, likely because you have employees assigned to more than one project. So as it stands, your query doesn't make sense - i.e. you cannot determine the project name from the employeee ID.

Comment: so suggest me , how to get rid of it

Comment: I'm saying that you can't do it. You cannot get a single project name when the only information you have is the employee ID.

Comment: @Vj charan, This is what happens when you do not post complete table schema and the sample data. The people need to assume and suggest the answer, which might not solve your problem.

Comment: i am getting the project name , i want from and to- date

Comment: @Vj charan, if you want the latest project assigned to employee, you might use `TOP 1` clause with `ORDER BY p.Id DESC`.

Comment: The error you posted shows that you are *NOT* getting the project name.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a query like this : 
set @VAR = (select column FROM table);

The select must return only one result.

You need to edit your query to make a TOP 1 or a GROUP BY to return only one result to assign at @VAR

Comment: actually i am trying to display all the reports of one emp, when i use @var its giving me the desired output for 1 record of emp but not all the records of same emp